# Angular ui-router adding /index.html/ into link from ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my AngularJS application.

I have element like

```
<a ui-sref="users({id: item.user_id})"></a>
```

but angular creating link like "www.domain.com/index.html/users/123" but all my links are without index.html. How can I remove it?

Comment: Give the absolute path on the route config file, when you declare the states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shaohao Lin for advice. Fixed by changing

```
<base href="/index.html"> to <base href="/">
```